# Delete a file after reading

Tags: python, file

In my code, user uploads file which is saved on server and read using the server path. I'm trying to delete the file from that path after I'm done reading it. But it gives me following error instead:

`An error occurred while reading file. [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

I'm reading file using `with`, and I've tried `f.close()` and also `f.closed` but its the same error every time.

This is my code:

```
f = open(filePath)
    with f:
        line = f.readline().strip()
        tempLst = line.split(fileSeparator)

        if(len(lstHeader) != len(tempLst)):
            headerErrorMsg = "invalid headers"
            hjsonObj["Line No."] = 1
            hjsonObj["Error Detail"] = headerErrorMsg
            data['lstErrorData'].append(hjsonObj)
            data["status"] = True

            f.closed
            return data                                                  

    f.closed
```

after this code I call the remove function:

```
os.remove(filePath)
```

**Edit:** using `with open(filePath) as f:` and then trying to remove the file gives the same error.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Please fix it. It is relevant. Also, put `os.remove(filePath)` together with the rest, so that we see its indentation as well. It is also relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
 f.closed
```

You need to say:

```
f.close()
```

`closed` is just a boolean property on the file object to indicate if the file is actually closed.

`close()` is method on the file object that actually closes the file.

Side note: attempting a file delete after closing a file handle is not 100% reliable. The file might still be getting scanned by the virus scanner or indexer.  Or some other system hook is holding on to the file reference, etc...  If the delete fails, wait a second and try again.

Comment: it's even better with `with open(filePath) as f:`. As soon as `f` goes out of scope it is closed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I WAS using `with open(filePath) as f:` before I changed it. It still gives same error. I've tried `f.close()` too

Answer (score 3):

Use below code:

```
import os
os.startfile('your_file.py')
```

To delete after completion:

```
os.remove('your_file.py')
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
import os

path = 'path/to/file'

with open(path) as f:
  for l in f:
    print l,

os.remove(path)
```

should work, with statement will automatically close the file after the nested block of code

if it fails, File could be in use by some external factor. you can use Redo pattern.

```
while True:
  try:
    os.remove(path)
    break
  except:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Believe me when I say I've tried every available solution including this one

Comment: @TahreemIqbal: What happens if you put a short time delay (eg [`time.sleep(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)) before attempting to remove the file? Are you _certain_ that the process that originally writes the file to disk has closed the file?

Comment: @PM2Ring `with open(path) as f:` is supposed to close the file right? I have tried the exact code provided by @Nima and bunch of other solutions too. I don't know why it won't work. But it isn't.

Comment: Yes, once the code leaves the `with` block the file will be closed. But my 2nd sentence was talking about the _server_ code that writes the file to disk, not the code you use to read the file.

Comment: @PM2Ring I checked that code. Here's the code for that
   `filePath = uploadFilePath + fileformat
        if not os.path.exists(filePath):
            print("no dir at " + filePath)
            os.makedirs(filePath)
    
        fd, filepath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=source.name, dir=filePath)
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as dest:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, dest)`
I tried adding `os.remove` right after uploading file and it gives the same error

Comment: @TahreemIqbal: It's hard to read multi-line Python code in comments, since they don't preserve indentation. But anyway... since you can't do `os.remove` after creating the file it looks like the writing process hasn't closed the file. Why are you using `shutil.copyfileobj` instead of just writing the file using `source.write`? I assume that `source` is a proper file or file-like object.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an application that is opening the file; check and close the application before executing your code:

```
os.remove(file_path)
```

Delete files that are not used by another application.